# How do I monitor bytes transferred in an Internet connection?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, modem, bandwidth

When I connect to the Internet in Xubuntu 19.04, there is an item in the Network Connections menu in the upper right corner of the desktop labeled "Connection Information", but it doesn't tell me how many bytes have been sent or received. Is there any way to get this information? (For reference, Windows allows you to click on the link for your Internet connection in Network And Sharing Center, and the window that pops up shows the total bytes sent and received on either side of the little pair of terminals that light up whenever data are moving back and forth.) My Internet connection is metered, and it would be good to know how much of my allotted bandwidth I am burning up while the connection is active. In Windows I can do this easily; in Xubuntu, I haven't found out how, yet.

Any suggestions offered would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 (and all flavors) is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 19.04 is EOL (End-of-life) and i strongly recommend update it.
However this works on any recent Ubuntu version (and in multiple flavours):

Using gnome-system-monitor you can measure the amount of data you have received and sent from your PC. You can install it by running this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

Then go to the resources tab and you will see the info you need under Network History. 
Hope it helps!